# Parameter passing and assert_difference

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, railstutorial.org

I am new to both Ruby and Rails. I don't understand why the following code (which uses Rails' `[ActiveSupport::Testing.assert_difference]`[1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-a_test_for_valid_submission) method) doesn't require a comma after the parameter `1`. The code comes from [Chapter 7](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-a_test_for_valid_submission) of the Rails Tutorial.

```
assert_difference 'User.count', 1 do
  post_via_redirect users_path, ...
end
```

The signature for `assert_difference` is:

```
assert_difference(expression, difference = 1, message = nil, &block)
```

thus I would expect that a comma would be required between the `difference` parameter and the `block` parameter but that is obviously not the case.

Why is the comma not required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Blocks aren't really parameters - what shows up in the method signature is that this method captures the block passed to it in a proc, but that is really an implementation detail that is leaked to the outside world. For example if you define a method like this

```
def foo(*args)
end
```

then blocks passed to this method don't end up in `args`.

However if you are passing a proc (or something that responds to `to_proc`), using the `&` argument prefix that you wish for this argument to be used as the method's block then you do need the comma.

```
my_proc = -> {post_via_redirect users_path}
assert_difference User.count, 1, &my_proc
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you are passing the block using the special `do |args| ... end`/`{ |args| ... }` notation. If you pass the block as a normal argument you need the comma:

```
block = proc { post_via_redirect users_path, ... }
assert_difference 'User.count', 1, &block
```

Answer (score 0):

Comma is not needed because this is how Ruby syntax works.

Block can be passed to method in 2 ways

1) Using `do ... end`

2) Using `{ ... }`

```
def some_method(&block)
  block.call
end

some_method { 2 + 2 }
#=> 4

some_method do
  2 + 2
end
#=> 4
```

Try this examples in console and you will understand them.